# Update Core Data on didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, didselectrowatindexpath

Alright, I've been at this for days and can't seem to figure out what I've been doing wrong.

What I want is the Core Data to update when a row is selected.  I got that down, but then I want the table view to refresh to display the change.  That is where I am having the problem.  I run:

```
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Root"];
    fetchedResultsController = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if(![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]){

    }
    [[self tabVe] reloadData];
```

after updating the data, but the tableview doesn't update.  I'll change views and come back, but it is.. stuck.  I can still scroll around and select more rows, but the table will never refresh. I have a segmented controller, and it works great changing the data the way I want to, but the reason I say the table gets stuck is because after I select a row, the segmented controller doesn't change the contents of the table like it would before a row was selected.

I am not doing this in edit mode, I just want it to update a value on being selected.  Here is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo name];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        [self.tabVe deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        if(cyc == 1){
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            }else {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
                Items *anItem = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                anItem.need = @"0";
                NSError *error = nil;
                if(![managedObjectContext save:&error]){

                }
                [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Root"];
                fetchedResultsController = nil;
                NSError *error = nil;
                if(![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]){

                }
                [[self tabVe] reloadData];
            }
        }
    }

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"name"] description];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"notes"] description];
    if([[managedObject valueForKey:@"need"] description] == @"0"){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }else if([[managedObject valueForKey:@"need"] description] == @"1"){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

I am hoping that someone can help me figure this out.  cyc is an NSInteger showing the current position of the segmented controller, I am currently only updating the item when cyc is equal to 1.

**Edit:**

Everything runs smoothly until

```
if(![managedObjectContext save:&error]){

}
```

is run.  After that, that is when the table seems to get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just guessing, but two things come to mind:

1. Try to cut down on the code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in my experience it is enough to simply set the `fetchedResultsController` to `nil` and let the lazy loading take care of the fetch. Another idea is to not use any cache at all. That would be worth a try, certainly reasonable if it does not hit performance.
2. I noticed that you are comparing two strings with `==`. I think you should be using the `isEqualToString:` method for this comparison. Also, I am not sure why you need the `description` method in addition to the string - the `description` of an `NSString` is exactly the same string. Try to simplify this also.

Also, from your code it is not clear what the variable `cyc` is and where it comes from. You might want to choose more human understandable variable names.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Unfortunately, setting `fetchedResultsController` to `nil` and not using a cache didn't get the table working.  

Also, I meant to use `isEqualToString` but completely forgot and went with old habits, so thank you for reminding me.  Not sure why I use `description`, I just do.  

Anyways, thanks for the help/advice, but I'm still having the same issues.

Comment: Did you put `cacheName:nil` in your `fetchedResultsController`'s `init`-method?

Comment: Yes, I put `cacheName:nil` in my `fetchedResultsController`'s `init` method.

Comment: I made my own workaround.  Not a proper one at all, but it works for my needs.  I am using a mix of sqlite3 and core data now.  I'll mark yours as the accepted answer since it helped me out :)

Comment: Thanks. What was the problem?

Comment: I did it this way: 

`NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [managedObject setValue:@"0" forKey:@"need"];`

And it's working fine now, even though the reason I tried the dot method was because it wasn't.  Oh well, it works now.

Comment: OK, I have a guess what did not work. I think you tried to set a property (an **object**) to `0`, a **primitive** type. The way to do this is `object.need = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];` or something like that.